# How to run two Messenger applications logged into different accounts?

Tags: applications, apk, processes

I have done a bit of research, and that, coupled with some programming knowledge, leads me to believe that it should be perfectly possible to run two separate applications of Facebook Messenger.

Is it as simple as changing the manifest file name? Or is there more to it? How do I run two separate Messengers?

Comment: I think the question can also be asked as how to run an app with two separate instances running with separate profile? More like Sandboxie application in Windows or Chroot environment in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at the *very least* that will have to be done. You may also have to re-sign the apk, and also change any absolute references to the Application context inside the java code and/or machine code. This will require lots of effort, you might as well build your own Messenger interface via Facebook's API. Facebook does have a developer API for this kind of stuff, you may want to look into that.

[Facebook Developer SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android)

I would try renaming the package first, without even decompiling anything, if it crashes due to internal package pointers, I would probably try to build a plug-in.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

There is also other ways to do this. Simply download other messenger apps like Nimbuzz to have multiple Facebook accounts.

If u need only Facebook's own messenger application,Try these simple steps. It may works.

1. Take the facebook messenger apk.
2. Decompile apk. [Decompile android](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) will do this for you.
3. Just change the package name.[from orca.facebook.com to anyother name]
4. Change the name in the manifest.
5. Recompile & build the app.
6. Install it in your phone.

Answer (score -1):

Now, Facebook only support multiple accounts. You can run more than one facebook account in facebook messenger app.

Follow this simple steps to add, remove and switch [multiple accounts in facebook messenger](http://www.indabaa.com/how-to-add-multiple-accounts-in-facebook-messenger-on-android/).

**Disclosure:** I'm the author of the linked article.

Answer (score -1):

I use one account with the APP and the other account with the Chrome navigator,

Comment: This seems like a possible answer. Could you elaborate on this and maybe add the steps for successfully using two accounts?